# PHP Password Hash Algorithm Result different from Javascript Result

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I i'm trying to convert a password hashing algorithm from PHP to Javascript for use with Node.JS. My results are different though for each version of the code. I think i've converted it correctly but maybe i've missed something.

Tested Password is: `Cake99`

- PHP result:

  > `2392893c9280d10e82fcef37be0e94df`
- JavaScript result:

  > `73a75e6c999d773460748e269ec324c4`

PHP version

```
function pCrypt($password)
{
    $md5password = 'superSecretMD5Pass';
    $s = md5($password) . md5($md5password);
    $j = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($s); $i++)
    {
        if ($j >= strlen($md5password)) $j = 0;
        $s[$i] = $s[$i] ^ $md5password[$j];
        $j++;
    }
    return md5($s);
}
```

JavaScript version

```
function pCrypt(password) {
    var md5password = 'superSecretMD5Pass';
    var s = md5(password) + md5(md5password);
    var j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (j >= md5password.length) {
            j = 0;
        }
        s[i] = s[i] ^ md5password[j];
        j++;
    }
    return md5(s);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug you should file with the package maintainers.

Comment: Why on earth would you use that hashing method anyway?!?!? http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666, The pure MD5 results match with no issue. I don't think it's the package.

Comment: @Petah, Have to for what i'm doing with it. No other option.

Comment: md5 is crap for password storing. All encryption algorithms are crap for password storing. Take a look at actual hashing.

Comment: Also see Openwall's [Portable PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords.

Comment: The application that validates the passwords does so using this method. I HAD to use this one as modifying the auth server to use something like BCrypt is not possible. It is a closed source Win32 app written many years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/

```
function pCrypt(password) {
    var md5password = 'superSecretMD5Pass';
    var s = md5(password) + md5(md5password);
    var r = '';
    var j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (j >= md5password.length) {
            j = 0;
        }
        r += String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(i) ^ md5password.charCodeAt(j));
        j++;
    }
    return md5(r);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I actually have one other i need help with also. Same situation, though now i have it working better ish than it was thanks to this solution. I can pay you for your time. Email me at a@dkai.dk. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript does not support bitwise operations using strings:

```
> "a"^"c"
0
```

Comment: Ahh ok, Thanks! Can you suggest an alternative or some sort of conversion?

Comment: @Andrew You might want to check out [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) and `String.charCodeAt`.

Comment: @Andrew But using a proper password hashing algorithm like bcrypt is even better.

Comment: I would love to use something more conventional but the app that reads these passwords cannot read them in any other format :/ Will check out those two methods now... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The PHP loop is iterating over bytes, while the JavaScript version is iterating over UTF-16/UCS-2 code-units which are each 2 bytes wide.